# how to show and hide by jQuery when click on a div and hide when click on body also

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a menu which is like a mobile menu.I want when i click on the image it will slide down and show the menu and when click on that image it will slide up. and also want when I click anywhere in the body it will slide up also. My menu is working when I click on the image and when i click on the body.

But cannot slide up the menu when click on image again.that's the problem.

I am using this code

```
$(".service_detail_menu img").click(function(e){
   $(".service_detail_menu ul").slideDown( 300 );
      e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $(".service_detail_menu ul").slideUp( 300 );
});
```

this is my link. click on 1st read more. you can see the menu.

http://goo.gl/gMeDgz

Thanks

Comment: You should create div that fills (overlays) whole document when menu is opened. Then just add click handler to that div and close the menu.

Comment: show html or more good is to provie jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
  $(".service_detail_menu img").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(".service_detail_menu ul").slideUp(300);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(".service_detail_menu ul").slideDown(300);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).parents(".service_detail_menu").length == 0) {
            $(".service_detail_menu ul").slideUp(300);
            $(".service_detail_menu img").removeClass('active');
        }
  });
```

Comment: hi , your code works. but when i click on body it is not working. i need it also worked when i click outside of the navigation image.anywhere i click it will slide up like my current code.

Comment: Welcome kapil, I have made a small change in a code, please go with that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use :visible or :hidden to check if the ul is visible, then slide up if it's visible.

```
$(".service_detail_menu img").click(function(e){ 
    $(".service_detail_menu ul:hidden").slideDown( 300 );
    $(".service_detail_menu ul:visible").slideUp(300);
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score -1):

try JQuery toggle - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. toggle will handle alternatives by itself.
write css to slideup and slidedown.